# SSRS Horizontal Range Chart Causes Double Pages to be Rendered

Tags: reporting-services, gantt-chart

I'm implementing a Gantt Chart in SSRS via the Horizontal Range Chart and notes I found here (http://pnarayanaswamy.blogspot.com/2010/09/range-bar-chart-gantt-chart-using-ssrs.html).  I've successfully implemented the Gantt Chart plus some additions so it can span multiple pages (DynamicHeight based on # of rows).  My problem is that no matter what I do, I end up with double blank pages at the end of the report.  I.e. if my Gantt chart is 10 pages, I'll have 10 blank pages at the end.

Any ideas?  It's most definitely not a margin issue, as I've removed everything from the report except the Gantt Chart and then made it 1" wide and still get the double-pages issue. It is always exactly double the # of pages it should be.  I've turned on all borders to see if there are any dynamically expanding boxes that might cause this but nothing is showing up. I'm open to ideas from anyone who has experienced anything similar.  This is probably rare, though, as charts don't typically span multiple pages.

Thanks for your help.

Rocky

Answer (score 1):

Even though you've explored a lot of the options, this still sound like a width issue. certainly a width issue: have you checked the width of the "Body" (That's the name that will show in the Properties pane.) You can find this by clicking on a blank part of the report, the background, and then use the properties pane to alter the width (The Body Properties dialog doesn't have options to change this.) Another way of changing these is by dragging the border of the page around in the designer.

Make sure that the width of the Body is less than your page width minus margins. Those, as it sounds like you know, are set in Report menu -> Report Properties.

Comment: I've checked and tested the body width... I can make the width 5in and make the chart 4in and then make the report 11x17 and it still doubles the pages. With as much testing I've done around minimizing the width, I'd be hard-pressed to believe it has anything to do with width. I'm leaning towards it being something about rendering a chart that spans multiple pages, though I haven't found any corroborating reports from anyone else.  Thanks